# Loading Remote Data using Select2 and Webservice

Tags: web-services, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 4.0.3 in my web forms .net application. I am trying to Load Remote data using a webservice, but its not working as expected.

First Issue am facing is that the webservice method is not getting called and am getting a console error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: text.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

So I tried removing the paremeter from the webservice call

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDataFromService() As String
```

Doing this the method got fired, but still the items in the select2 did not get populated (screenshot atached[image]).

Can someone help me to figure out where am I making a mistake.

Here are the details:

Select2 Code in the Webform:

```js
 $("#ddlEntity").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "Service/InvoiceHTMLService.asmx/GetDataFromService",
            type: 'POST',
            delay: 250,
            params: {
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    text: term,
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                // scrolling can be used
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    });
```

```
WebService Method:
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetDataFromService(text As String) As String 
        Return "{['id':1, 'text':'Test1'],['id':2, 'text':'Test2']}"
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("text",term);
ajax: {
 url: "Service/InvoiceHTMLService.asmx/GetDataFromService",
 type: 'POST',
 delay: 250,
 params: {
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 data: fd
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not create template for this select2. since you are using  templateResult and templateSelection it requires template or you can remove those two options.

For your reference : https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating

Updated:

they have changed query callback from

```
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                text: term,
            };
        },
```

into

```
   data: function (params) {
  return {
    q: params.term, // search term
    page: params.page
  };
},
```

Comment: I removed both the Template options, still the both the issue remain, neither the webservice is getting called, not data is being returned.

Comment: oops response should be array objects like Return [{'id':1, 'text':'Test1'},
 {'id':2, 'text':'Test2'}]

Comment: I am able to get the data back, but the primary issue as i have mentioned in the post as well is that I am not being able to get the web service method called with the text parameter, If I keep it blank, it works. But I need the typed text as a parameter, so that I can get the data filtered.

Comment: they changed      

data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },

reference : https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax